# How can I write the name show in axis of 3D array using TiKz

Tags: tikz-styles, block

I am drawing a 3D array like the attached picture, which actually describes a multidimensional array. However, I can not put the name of the axis and take the value from the matrix like the attached picture.
[image]
This is the code that I have:

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={anchor=north east,fill=white,minimum width=1.4cm,minimum height=7mm}]
\matrix (mA) [draw,matrix of math nodes]
{
(1,1,3) & (1,1,3) & (1,1,3) & (1,1,3) \\
(1,1,3) & (1,1,3) & (1,1,3) & (1,1,3) \\
(1,1,3) & (1,1,3) & (1,1,3) & (1,1,3) \\
(1,1,3) & (1,1,3) & (1,1,3) & (1,1,3) \\
};

\matrix (mB) [draw,matrix of math nodes] at ($(mA.south west)+(1.5,0.7)$)
{
(1,1,3) & (1,1,3) & (1,1,3) & (1,1,3) \\
(1,1,3) & (1,1,3) & (1,1,3) & (1,1,3) \\
(1,1,3) & (1,1,3) & (1,1,3) & (1,1,3) \\
(1,1,3) & (1,1,3) & (1,1,3) & (1,1,3) \\
};

\matrix (mC) [draw,matrix of math nodes] at ($(mB.south west)+(1.5,0.7)$)
{
(1,1,3) & (1,1,3) & (1,1,3) & (1,1,3) \\
(1,1,3) & (1,1,3) & (1,1,3) & (1,1,3) \\
(1,1,3) & (1,1,3) & (1,1,3) & (1,1,3) \\
(1,1,3) & (1,1,3) & (1,1,3) & (1,1,3) \\
};

\draw[dashed](mA.north east)--(mC.north east);
\draw[dashed](mA.north west)--(mC.north west);
\draw[dashed](mA.south east)--(mC.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Comment: It is possible to place [text along a path](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/76172/tikz-text-along-path-as-node). It is also possible to [bend the text along a curve](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22314/tikz-bend-text-so-that-it-follows-a-line).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Each matrix is a node, and has the usual anchors, so just place nodes relative to those,

To highlight a specific node in a matrix, add options to that cell with `|[<options>]|` added to the start of the cell.

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={anchor=north east,fill=white,minimum width=1.4cm,minimum height=7mm}]
\matrix (mA) [draw,matrix of math nodes]
{
(1,1,3) & (1,1,3) & (1,1,3) & (1,1,3) \\
(1,1,3) & (1,1,3) & (1,1,3) & (1,1,3) \\
(1,1,3) & (1,1,3) & (1,1,3) & (1,1,3) \\
(1,1,3) & (1,1,3) & (1,1,3) & (1,1,3) \\
};

\matrix (mB) [draw,matrix of math nodes] at ($(mA.south west)+(1.5,0.7)$)
{
(1,1,3) & (1,1,3) & (1,1,3) & (1,1,3) \\
(1,1,3) & (1,1,3) & (1,1,3) & (1,1,3) \\
(1,1,3) & (1,1,3) & (1,1,3) & (1,1,3) \\
(1,1,3) & (1,1,3) & (1,1,3) & (1,1,3) \\
};

\matrix (mC) [draw,matrix of math nodes] at ($(mB.south west)+(1.5,0.7)$)
{
(1,1,3) & (1,1,3) & (1,1,3) & (1,1,3) \\
(1,1,3) & (1,1,3) & |[draw=red]|(1,1,3) & (1,1,3) \\
(1,1,3) & (1,1,3) & (1,1,3) & (1,1,3) \\
(1,1,3) & (1,1,3) & (1,1,3) & (1,1,3) \\
};

\draw[dashed](mA.north east)--(mC.north east);
\draw[dashed](mA.north west)-- node[sloped,above] {Number} (mC.north west);
\draw[dashed](mA.south east)--(mC.south east);

\node [above left] at (mC.north) {Column};
\node [left] at (mC.west) {Row};

\draw (mC-2-3) to[out=260,in=200] ++(5cm,-1cm) node[right] {$(1,1,3)$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: How can I move the "number" or "column" to righr or left about 1cm? Thanks a lot for your guide.

Comment: @user3727281 For `column`, add `xshift=1cm` to the node options. For `number`, add `pos=0.4` to the node options (The default in that case is `midway`, which is the same as `pos=0.5`. The number is the fractional position along the line, so 0.5 is 50% along the distance of the line.)

Comment: how can I reduce the size of the 3D matrix? Thanks a lot for your helping

Comment: @user3727281 You can reduce the size of the nodes in the matrices, by changing `minimum width` and `height` in the `every node` style, you can add `inner sep=0, font=\scriptsize` to the `every node` style to remove some whitespace and reduce the fontsize, and you can move the three matrices closer together, by changing the offset, i.e. in `($(mA.south west)+(1.5,0.7)$)` change the values in `(1.5,0.7)`. For example.