# TikZ: text along path as node (again)

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, decorations

I would like to ask again the following question:

[TikZ: text along path as node](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/76172/tikz-text-along-path-as-node?newreg=f87e79c08ea6409db09687e2f7d937ec)

That question was answered with a solution which was good enough for OP at the time. I would, however like to have an answer to the question as posed originally.

More specifically, I want to have a text following a curved path (for instance using decorations) and then use that text to fit a shape around it. In this example, I would like to draw an ellipse fitting "stuff" and "along path" but I don't know how to refer to "along path" because it has no node name.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text,fit,shapes}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (A) at (-2,2) {stuff};
  \draw[postaction={decorate,decoration={
      text along path,
      text={along path},
      % name = (B),  <--- this does not work
      raise = 3
    }}] (-1,0) to [out= 90, in=90] (1,0);
  % \draw[fit=(A)(B), ellipse]{}; <---- I want to be able to do this
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You have already done what you want. Please can you explain what you want by a sketch?

Comment: I want to draw a shape (for instance an ellipse) fitting tightly around the words “stuff” and “along path”.

Comment: I have edited the question. It should hopefully be more clear now.